# I wish to add an extra price column in the product ordered report

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.0

[image]

I want to add price column after sku in this report is there any solution please ?

Comment: please share your code so we can understand better.

Comment: This is something there in under report menu. not my code.

Answer (score 0):

if you have created listing using Ui component then here is the solution

```
<column name="price">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Comment: where i can find the ordered product report file.

Comment: @MohammedAslam if you please share a screenshot, that what you actually want to do then it will be easy to understand. If you want to change something in the core module then you need to create your custom module.